# Using positioning and margins on Flexboxes?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

```
<template>
  <div class="flex justify-center">
    <div class="h-px-500 md:w-1/6 bg-orange-200 text-center">1</div>
    <div class="h-px-500 md:w-1/6 bg-orange-300 text-center">2</div>
    <div class="h-px-500 md:w-1/6 bg-orange-400 text-center">3</div>
</div>
</template>
```

If i wanted to place this Flexbox somewhere on the screen.. How do i go about it? For example top: 75%? Cannot figure it out. I dont want to use "w-screen h-screen" as it blocks me from placing out many flexboxes on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a parent div and make the parent div position absolute then position that.

```
<div class="absolute">
    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="h-px-500 md:w-1/6 bg-orange-200 text-center">1</div>
        <div class="h-px-500 md:w-1/6 bg-orange-300 text-center">2</div>
        <div class="h-px-500 md:w-1/6 bg-orange-400 text-center">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```